# Did any 5.25" floppy drives not based on the Apple Disk II offer quarter-track control

Tags: apple-ii, floppy-disk, floppy-drive

Unlike many drives, the Apple Disk II has inputs that control the individual head stepper coils.  These are commonly described as advancing by half-tracks, since advancing a full track requires activating two coils in sequence.  Four-pole stepper motors, however, can not only be moved by driving coils individually, but also by driving pairs of coils.  Since advancing by one pole moves a half track, energizing a pair of cells will access a quarter-track location between two half-track locations.

Experimentally, at least on the Apple //c, when writing data sequentially, it's possible to write data at 3/4-track intervals and then read back previously written tracks.  For test purposes, I used a program that packs twelve double-high-res graphics pictures into the space of 27 normal tracks (2.25 tracks each) and allows random access via keyboard.  I likely could have used 15 if I'd had that many DHGR pictures handy.  This would likely not be reliable if tracks were being written by different drives at different times, and I'm not sure how reliable it would be for data written using one drive and read using another (I just have one drive on my Apple //c) but the fact that this works at all would suggest that it could be expected to be reliable if information were written on quality media using a drive specialized for the purpose--something that could have been really great for copy-protection purposes if a game would make use of data in a way that effectively required 200K to fit on a single disk ("normal" Apply formatting is 35 tracks of 16 sectors of 256 bytes, but the game Prince of Persia used a format that packed 4.5K bytes per track, which would allow 35 tracks to hold 157.5K); 200K would have exceeded that by a substantial margin.

Were there any other floppy drive systems that offered quarter-track control, or high-density systems that offered half-track control, or was such ability unique to the Disk-II style systems?

Comment: You mean beside other Apple drives? --- Also, nice hack, like it. Has been done back in the days. Yields about10-15 extra tracks (upper limit when going beyond track 35 - most drives can do 40 to 44). It's worth to keep the first tree tracks separated by 4 steps. to ease unusual loaders. Hacking RWTS for 3 steps is possible

Comment: @Raffzahn: Is it reliable for uses cases other than writing tracks sequentially using only one drive?  I would think that writing a track would slightly disturb the contents of tracks that are 0.75 away; such disturbance seems tolerable when it only occurs on one side, but writing the tracks both 0.75 above and 0.75 below a track would increase the likelihood of corruption.  Further, if the track below were written from a drive that wrote it 0.05 tracks above the expected position, while the track above were written by one that wrote it 0.05 tracks below, that would encroach even more.

Comment: @Raffzahn: If this were at all common back in the day, I would think emulators would support it.  In any case, my question is about drives which aren't designed for media compatibility with the Disk II.

Comment: Didn't say all that common, just it has been used. After all, it's only used in a closed setup with a modified RWTS, so anyone who wanted to exchange disks outside had to use standard format, as Apple DOS cold not be adjusted dynamic. So essential only for private datadisks or alike. Track stepping width of SA400 is ~500 µm (48 TPI), while trackwidth (defined by the head) is 300 µm (330 with some security). So this allows outting tracks closer and still be (fairly) transportable.

Comment: @Raffzahn: BTW, one thing I've been pondering would be writing some code for the 1541 or 1571 which would take data written using the Apple II and re-encode it at a somewhat faster rate.  I think the Apple could write but not read data in a form that the 1541 could accept, and the Apple can accept data that's written on outer tracks at a rate aboiut 25% faster than normal, but I think the 1541 and 1571 would be limited to half-track resolution.

Comment: It has definitely been used.  Some Apple II games had the data written is a single spiral track as copyright protection.

Comment: @RETRAC: I'm aware of spiral tracks, but from my understanding the clearance between adjacent tracks was always at least four half-steps.

Comment: Somewhat relatedly, there is a PC 3.5” drive with its head controlled by a voice coil (as in a hard disk) rather than a stepper motor. This allows it to make finer, more precise steps and the drive can therefore format a regular 1.44MB disk to 32MB capacity.

Comment: @ZaneKaminski: I would not expect that pushing track spacing that tight would yield even remotely usable results.  The 33% packing using 3/4 track spacing works, at least on my machine.

Comment: It did exist, though it was not widely deployed. The standard is called “FD32MB”. The catch is that the disk is read-only after being written. The idea is, the floppy medium can be very dense in the rotational axis, so a track can hold several tens of thousands of bits. The reason the track spacing cannot achieve this density is the mechanical limitations on precise head positioning, not any directionality of the magnetic medium. Using a voice coil rather than a stepper motor solved this to some extent, so the FD32MB drives can position themselves over ~800 tracks, as I recall.

Comment: @ZaneKaminski: Adding a read-only-after-writing restriction could help things a lot.  A major difficulty with trying to push density is that it's very hard to control the size of the spot which is being written.  If the spot being written is multiple tracks wide, but a disk is written purely in order, then each area of the disk will be left with whatever was last written to it.  I'm not sure how one would.  I guess if a disk has a read head which is positioned toward outside from the write head, it might be possible to have a "drive" experiment with voice coil and write currents...

Comment: ...while starting to write a disk, until it finds the optimal combination given the temperature of the system and the characteristics of the media, and then start writing data once it had dialed in the right parameters.  That could have been a neat concept for backups in the era of 40-250MB tapes, even if it wouldn't be any faster.

Comment: Spacing tracks 3/4 instead of 1/1 is a gamble, because you rely on the R/W-head being small enough to not overwrite data on a different track. That might already fail on a single drive where the R/W head was a bit wider (but still within the expected tolerance). "Quality media" has nothing to do with it, it's all about the width of the R/W-head.

Comment: @dirkt: If a drive head were the full width of a track, repeated writes to a track would tend to disturb the contents of adjacent tracks.  Further, if using good quality media, one could write tracks that were half the normal width with 1/4 track of blank space between whose magnetic domains were polarized in a direction perpendicular to those used to write data, and the automatic gain control would compensate by boosting the weaker signal (which, if one was using good quality media, might be stronger than a signal produced by a normal-width track with lesser quality media).

Comment: @supercat Of course the drive head is not "the full width of the track". The distance between tracks is such that under normal conditions, writes to adjacent tracks don't disturb each other. If you reduce the distance between tracks to 3/4, you do risk overwrites (because otherwise one could have just reduced the normal diistance between tracks by 3/4). You can't influence "track width written", not without special equipment. The head differed between **different** floppies, that's why DD floppies formatted in an HD drive (with smaller head) sometimes wouldn't work in a DD drive.

Comment: @supercat For example, have a look at [this image](https://twitter.com/Foone/status/1307421024913207296) of the flux on a floppy. These are normally spaced tracks. They are distanced enough that If you move them closer by 3/4, they'll start to touch. This will work fine if stepper is precise enough that the head always gets centered. If it's not, reading or writing may overlap with the neighbouring track, risking read errors or data loss.

Comment: @dirkt: If a software company were to record drives with specialized equipment, it could write them tighter than normal without them touching.  I would not expect disks to be reliable if written and updated using ordinary drives, but my reference to "quality media" also referred to the use of specialized equipment to write the disks.  From a software vendor's perspective, the fact that the software vendor's special equipment could write information that ordinary drives couldn't write reliably would be a benefit.  Otherwise, experiments show that it's possible to write 16 double hi-res...

Comment: ...pictures to a disk and read them back in desired sequence if a user types A-P, provided that any seek from a higher track to a lower track uses an intervening seek to a track that's one below the target followed by the desired track.  Reads will often succeed even without the extra seek for backlash compensation, but it makes things much more consistent.

Comment: @supercat "If a software company were to record drives with specialized equipment, it could write them tighter than normal without them touching." Yes, it could. If you had floppy drives with smaller heads, or with multiple heads of different size, then you could do that also in drives connected to the Apple II. But we are not talking about those, we are talking about normal Apple drives, used for both reading and writing (or at least I thought we were talking about those). All I am saying is "if you read and write 3/4 tracks on a normal drive, it's a gamble; you risk errors".

Comment: @dirkt: What *I* was talking about in that paragraph was what would be possible for a company wishing to produce software for use in a stock Disk II.  Many software companies recorded information on disks in ways that could be read but not reproduced by a stock Disk II, though usually for purposes of copy-protection rather than capacity enhancement.

Comment: @supercat even if you just read with a stock Disk II, you risk errors. If you make the "special" R/W-head smaller, you decrease the flux change when read with a stock head, so you must increase magnetization, which means you must probably change the surface coating, and so on, and so on. Then you are basically inventing a new disk format, which is just too much effort and not cost efficient (though it may be theoretically possible). If, OTOH, you keep the stock head, then on different drives the head won't necessarily be centered, and will read a mix of this track and the adjacent track.

Comment: And while noise cancels out, the flux change in the adjacent track is ordered, so you'll weaken the signal of the current track. If you **really** want closer tracks, the correct way  is to define a completely new disk format (let's call it "HD"): smaller heads, higher track density, different amplifier, different surface coating. Anything else might work by chance on your single drive, but risks errors otherwise. Because the distance between tracks is the way it is for a reason.

Comment: @dirkt: Some surface coatings produce stronger magnetic responses than others.  Drives have automatic gain control circuitry to compensate for this.  If the software house uses media whose response it at the high end of what is available, and writes gaps between tracks, then a drive which is capable of reliably supporting random reads and writes with lesser quality media, and allows fine control of head movement, would likely be able to reliably read enhanced-density data.  Track density is at it is to allow for reliable retrieval...

Comment: ...of data written in random order on media of varying quality by drives with loose tolerances.  If data will be written in fixed sequence by drives that are precisely calibrated, and if the software that reads the disk would be able to 'nudge' the head movement timing if needed, those factors should increase the density with which information could be written while still being readable by a stock Disk II.

Comment: @dirkt: Incidentally, if a track is written by drive #1, and a sector is overwritten using drive #2 which has the head positioned slightly inward from that drive #1, then if drive #1 reads that sector, some residual information will be left over from the original write, within the part of the disk that drive #1 wrote to (and would write again).  Drives need to be able to tolerate the presence of a certain amount of stray junk near the edges of the regions where they would write data, whether such stray junk is a previous version of the same track, or data from the next track.

Answer (score 4):

The Disk-II mechanism is essentially a floppy drive with the low-level controller ripped out. Few, if any, other manufacturers were willing to do that, as it means a more complex controller and connection to the computer.

Drive mechanisms from the Shugart SA-400 onwards used just two lines — Direction and Step — to manage the heads. To manage the four bipolar stepper motor lines required far more complex timing and switching, and while the Disk-II controller is a marvel of electronics, it was also implementing a solved problem. It seemed to be more important to Apple at the time to produce a low parts cost design that maximised profit than to get a working drive to market quickly.

By the time other competitors to Apple were implementing disk drives, rapid time to market was more important than gaining a few more bytes on a disk by designing your own low-level controller. It was also likely that the disk drive market was larger, and no one buyer would have enough clout to demand their own weird controller-less variant.

I know of no other computer company that went Apple's way. That's not to say that someone else didn't, but the reasons for Apple making the choices they did were very specific to their market entry time and their technical team being very close to management.

Comment: Ironically, the Apple Disk Controller II is among the simplest anywhere.  I think Woz pushed his penny pinching a bit further than would be ideal, since it took many years before disk routines appeared that could read *and decode* a full track worth of 6:2 data in a single revolution.

Comment: sure, it's simple: but it takes up all of the CPU's cycles to manage the process, and sending stepper drive pulses the full length of a cable probably seemed a great idea at the time.

Comment: The current for the stepper motor is switched within the drive itself, so the cable is simply carrying four logic-level signals for the heads.  Were there any mass-market drives that could use GCR encoding without using the CPU to read or write individual bytes?

Comment: Can't say for certain. Apple's IWM/SWIM looks like it can return bytes with only an address and a clock (??). The Amiga's controller was a track-at-once DMA thing for 3½" drives could do GCR, in theory. After the IBM PC, GCR became pretty niche and likely not worth the effort unless you had compatibility to maintain

Comment: FM requires two encoded bits for each bit of data, and can generate one flux transition per bit.  GCR on the Apple requires 8 for 6, and on the Commodore requires 5 for 4, again with up to one flux transition per bit.  MFM uses two encoded bits per bit of data, but never writes two consecutive flux transitions, thus allowing use of a raw data rate twice as high as FM.

Comment: Struggling with the relevance of that. Maybe you can find a computer/drive introduced after the Apple Mac that used GCR. I can't. MFM had won by then. GCR and variable-speed drives were just not worth the effort when the media was only $2/each.

Comment: MFM required doubling the raw bit rate, and required increased timing precision, which made the front-end hardware a little more tricky to implement.  Hard drives moved on from MFM to use RLL, which is something of a hybrid between MFM and GCR.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be games that used half tracks, and I believe, quarter tracks for copyright protection.

Skipping half tracks in the middle was fairly common, there were special copy programs that could copy those disks but they where unreliable and took forever. If a normal floppy was written as 1 3 5 7 9 half track such a disk would be written as 1 3 6 8 10 and such pattens. It would reduce the capacity of the disk a bit but make it harder to copy.

As for quarter tracks I recall one program that wrote the floppy disk as a sort of quantum vinyl record with a spiral jumping a quarter track to the inside every quarter rotation.

You could read by reading all the quarter quarter tracks to find the legitimate block of data with a marker. I suspect you would need a special modified disk drive to write such things, or very precise timing.